# Production ready user signup, login and logout using python and tornado

Tags: python, security, tornado

Please review my code with the following in mind: Does anyone see a reason to make this asynchronous, why would i do that? How do i work out the maximum number of users it can handle at one time? at what point will i need to optimise it and are there any easy things i can do to handle more users.

```
import os
import sqlite3
import hashlib
import binascii
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.web import Application, RequestHandler
from tornado.options import define, options


define('port', default=80, help='port to listen on')

settings = dict(
    template_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates"),
    static_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static"),
    debug=True,
    cookie_secret="changethis",
    login_url="/login",
    # xsrf_cookies=True,
)

def hash_password(password):
    """Hash a password for storing."""
    salt = hashlib.sha256(os.urandom(60)).hexdigest().encode('ascii')
    pwdhash = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha512', password.encode('utf-8'), 
                                salt, 100000)
    pwdhash = binascii.hexlify(pwdhash)
    return (salt + pwdhash).decode('ascii')

def verify_password(stored_password, provided_password):
    """Verify a stored password against one provided by user"""
    salt = stored_password[:64]
    stored_password = stored_password[64:]
    pwdhash = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha512', 
                    provided_password.encode('utf-8'), 
                    salt.encode('ascii'), 100000)
    pwdhash = binascii.hexlify(pwdhash).decode('ascii')
    return pwdhash == stored_password

try:
    db = sqlite3.connect('file:aaa.db?mode=rw', uri=True)
except sqlite3.OperationalError:
    db = sqlite3.connect("aaa.db")
    db.execute("CREATE TABLE Users (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, username TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE, password TEXT NOT NULL);")

class BaseHandler(RequestHandler):
    def get_current_user(self):
        return self.get_secure_cookie("session")

class IndexHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        if not self.current_user:
            self.write("not logged in")
            return
        count = db.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users;").fetchone()
        self.write('{} users so far!'.format(count[0]))

class LoginHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        if self.current_user:
            self.write("already logged in")
            return
        self.render("login.html")
    def post(self):
        if self.current_user:
            self.write("already logged in")
            return
        name=self.get_body_argument("username")
        query= db.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE username = ?;", (name,)).fetchone()
        if query[0] == 0:
            self.write("user does not exist")
        else:
            hashed_password = db.execute("SELECT (password) FROM Users WHERE username = ?;", (name,)).fetchone()[0]
            if verify_password(hashed_password, self.get_body_argument("password")):
                self.set_secure_cookie("session", name)
                self.write("cookie set, logged in")
            else:
                self.write("wrong password")

class SignupHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        if self.current_user:
            self.write("already logged in")
            return
        self.render("signup.html")
    def post(self):
        if self.current_user:
            self.write("already logged in")
            return
        name=self.get_body_argument("username")
        password=self.get_body_argument("password")
        try:
            with db:
                db.execute("INSERT INTO Users(username,password) VALUES (?,?);", (name, hash_password(password)))
        except sqlite3.IntegrityError:
            self.write("user exists")
            return
        self.write("user added")

class LogoutHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.clear_cookie("session")
        self.write("logged out")

def main():
    routes=(
            (r'/', IndexHandler),
            (r'/login', LoginHandler),
            (r'/logout', LogoutHandler),
            (r'/signup', SignupHandler),
        )
    app = Application(routes, **settings)
    app.listen(options.port)
    IOLoop.current().start()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Welcome to the code review site where we review working code to provide suggestions on how to improve the code. It is not clear that you are asking for a code review, in fact it almost seems like you are asking for a feature request which would make the question off-topic for code review. Please see the guidelines at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask.

Comment: haha i got told the opposite on stackoverflow

Comment: The rewording the question definitely helped.